# The server receives an HTTP request body that is different from what was sent

Tags: http

**FOREWORD**

This may well be the weirdest problem I have ever witnessed in 15 years. It is 100% reproducible on a specific machine that sends a specific request when authenticated as a specific user, if the request is sent from Chrome (it doesn't happen from Edge, it doesn't happen from cURL or Postman). I can't expect an exact solution to my disturbingly specific issue, but **any pointers about what could theoretically cause it are more than welcome**.

**WHAT HAPPENS**

We have several PCs in our factory, that communicate with a central HTTP server (hosted on premise, if that even matters: they're on the same LAN). Of course, we have users who could work on any of these machines.

When a certain user does a specific action on a certain one of those machines, she gets a message about an "HTTP error". The server responds with a 400, specifying that the JSON in the request is ill-formed. Fine, let's look at the JSON: it's an 80-characters string, and it looks very well-formed. I check its length, and it is in fact an 80-character string, and the request has a `Content-Length` of 80. All is fine, but the server responds with the 400.

The same user on a different machine, or a different user on the same machine, or any other user on any other machine can do the very same action and the very same corresponding HTTP request. The same user, on that machine, can do the action fine using Edge instead of Chrome (despite both being Chromium-based). If I "export" the request from the browser's Dev Tools into any format (cURL bash, cURL cmd, JS fetch...), the request in Chrome and the one in Edge look the same.

Our UI sends the request using Axios. If I send it with fetch, I still get the error. If I serialize the JSON myself and send the string (instead of letting Axios/fetch handle the serialization), I still get the error. If I send that same request using any other client (cURL from command line, Postman...) I *don't* get the error - same as in Edge.

**WHAT I FINALLY NOTICED (and how I hacked the issue into submission)**

The server is ASP.NET Core (using .Net 5), so I added a middleware to record the received request. Apparently, in the specified conditions, **the server receives a request body that is different from what was sent by the client**. Say the client sends:

```
{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}
```

Well, the server receives:

```
{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"
```

Notice the newline at the beginning and the missing closing brace at the end. The body apparently gets an extra character at the start, and the final character is lost - either because it is not actually sent/received or because the `Content-Length` dictated it to be truncated.

This clearly explains the failed deserialization (the string is in fact invalid JSON) and the resulting 400 response.

Since this bug had been blocking or hindering production for several days, I wrote a "healer" middleware, that tries to deserialize the JSON string received (if the `Content Type` indicates JSON, of course); if it fails, it looks for a single non-opening-brace character at the start of the string, and if it finds it it rewrites the body by removing that character and appending a closing brace. It lets the healed request go down the pipeline and notifies me via e-mail.

**THE AFTERMATH**

All has been working fine since I released the fix, and we even asked or system managers to replace the PC that was causing problems, since we could only think of a vicious issue with OS/browser setup or configuration that caused conflicts.

However, when they replaced it, I started getting the notification e-mail again... this time from other two users, always on that same machine, each of them having the same issue (that is being healed, btw), each of them on a different request (but always the same request for each user). The requests point to different URLs and their bodies have different lengths and complexity (JSON-wise). I haven't tried all the tests I did before (different browser, cURL, fetch...) but the diagnosis of the problem is the same, and it is being handled by the healer middleware.

A colleague reported that they already had a similar problem several months ago, which they didn't investigate back then. They're not sure it was the very same workstation, but they replaced the PC and the error didn't happen any more. It seems to be pretty much random, and I still have no idea what could cause such a behaviour.

Here is some more info about the platform, if any of this is relevant:

- **clients**: Windows 10 PCs, using Chrome in kiosk mode, launched by a batch that is located on a network share;
- **UI**: React, sending HTTP requests with Axios;
- **server**: .Net 5 ASP.NET Core service.

**UPDATE**

I've recorded the network traffic using Wireshark on the client PC. Here is what I got:

[image: Screenshot of Wireshark capture]

So apparently the request is already modified when it leaves the client host.

Comment: Have you analyzed the network traffic using Wireshark or similar? Have you tried deleting the user's local chrome profile on the machine this happens on?

Comment: I was about to say the same thing as @gmiley. The first step is to isolate the problem to the client or the server. The recording middleware can't tell you that, since the server handles the request before it gets to it. Use Wireshark or similar to look at the network traffic, that way you know for sure whether the error is being introduced by the client or the server.

Comment: @gmiley I doubt it can be the user's Chrome profile, because if user X, who has the problem, logs out (from the app, not Windows or Chrome profile) and user Y logs in (same Chrome profile, same Windows user), then everything works fine for user Y.

Comment: Wireshark is pretty much the only thing left to try. The middleware was registered as the first of the pipeline, so it's the first thing that gets the request *once it reaches the application* - of course any layer before the application may introduce the issue. But I have no idea why any layer in between would transform the body in that peculiar way...

Comment: It looks like the end brace is there, though? So the client is probably just sending the extra newline, with the server cutting off the end due to the `Content-Length`. Can you confirm that the `Content-Length` matches the newline-less body length? And that working requests don't have that extra newline? I would then double-check what Developer Tools says it's sending on these broken requests. It might be hard to see that newline, depending on the format. The HAR format is probably your best bet.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry My fault for obfuscating too much of the body. The closing brace is there, but it does not match the one at the start: there is a property whose value is an object. The correct ending would be `"FN "}}`. `Content-Length` matches: the extra char is actually not sent. Working requests do not have that extra newline at the start, already checked.